# Direction to angle

Tags: c++, math

I'm not very good at math( and i never was ) and I've a problem: I'm trying to make sprite always rotated to mouse cursor. That's what i have:

```
 // mx is mouse X and my is mouse y
 double rotate = (atan2(my, mx) * PI);

 // Set rotation takes rotation in degrees
 ship.SetRotation( rad2deg(rotate) );
```

Where `deg2rad` function is:

```
double rad2deg(double rad)
{
    double deg = 0;
    deg = rad * (180/M_PI);
    return deg;
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working. The ship is rotating very weird ( really hard to define that  ). And I don't have any idea to solve this problem.

I'm working on SFML and [`SetRotation`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Drawable.php#a3e7d558d0ef488485a2d3f885ff2b419) takes degrees.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you casting to float and assigning to a double?

Comment: Are you sure that SetRotation expect degree and not radians?

Comment: Which framework has a setRotation that accepts degrees? Yuck. Are mx and my relative to the position of the ship? You might need to manually check their signs to cope with the case when they're both negative - you'd compute the angle when they're both positive back.

Comment: you need not mx and my. You need mx-x and my-y, where x and y is your sprite center to rotate it to the proper angle.

Comment: @Rup: OpenGL's `glRotate` takes degrees. Yuck, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the rotation relative to some point. Currently you're doing it relative to the corner of the screen, which will only give you 90 degrees and is probably not what you want. You probably want rotation relative to the sprite's location or perhaps relative to the centre of the screen, e.g.

```
// define centre of screen
const int Y0 = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
const int X0 = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;

// get rotation angle of mouse location relative to centre of screen
double rotate = (float) (atan2(Y0 - my), ((mx - X0));
```

[*As others have noted, e.g. @duffymo, you may also have the arguments to atan2 transposed, so I've made this change also.*]

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have wrong argument order for [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/). And also the values you pass to `atan2` should be relative mouse position to the object. So if object position is `ox`, `oy`, then you should use `atan2(my-oy, mx-ox)`.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you have the arguments to [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/) reversed.  The typical order is y first, then x.  Are you sure you know what you're passing to that method?

"not working" and "weird" don't help us understand what the problem is, so it's hard to help you.